# Как получить полную расшифровку стека утечек в fastmm4 для dll

Tags: delphi, утечка-памяти

Есть основная exe и dll. Fastmm4 прописан и там и там как основной менеджер памяти:

[image: Основное приложение]

И в dll

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В FastMM4Options.inc прописаны настройки (может еще какие-то есть,сюда выписал основные, что вспомнил точно прописывал :))

```
{$define FullDebugMode}
  {$define RawStackTraces}
{$define EnableMemoryLeakReporting}
  {$define HideExpectedLeaksRegisteredByPointer}
  {.$define RequireIDEPresenceForLeakReporting}
{$define ShareMM}
  {$define ShareMMIfLibrary}
{$define AttemptToUseSharedMM}
```

И в приложении и в dll прописаны настройка на отладочную информацию, создание map файла и т.д. по инструкциям из интернета.

EXE:

[image: Настройки exe]
[image: Настройки exe]

DLL:

[image: Настройки DLL]
[image: Настройки DLL]

Далее создаю специально утечку в теле DLL:

```
...    
TList.Create;
...
```

Перед закрытием приложения делаю полный дамп через вызов LogAllocatedBlocksToFile
В результате в файле дампа получаю детальный стек с описанием по моей (пока еще будущей) утечки:

```
Allocated block logged by LogAllocatedBlocksToFile. The size is: 20

This block was allocated by thread 0x2398, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
FDE6C42 [System.pas][System][@GetMem$qqri][4565]
FDE78FB [System.pas][System][TObject.NewInstance$qqrv][15975]
FDE8076 [System.pas][System][@ClassCreate$qqrpvzc][17290]
FDE79F0 [System.pas][System][TObject.$bctr$qqrv][16039]
FED9E67 [uLIB_Server.pas][uLIB_Server][TServerApp.getNextDataEx$qqrx24System.%DynamicArray$uc%rir27System.%AnsiStringT$us$i0$%t2ro][619]
FED9E73 [uLIB_Server.pas][uLIB_Server][TServerApp.getNextDataEx$qqrx24System.%DynamicArray$uc%rir27System.%AnsiStringT$us$i0$%t2ro][622]
FED5D9F [uServer.pas][uServer][TServerApp.getNextData$qqrx24System.%DynamicArray$uc%rir27System.%AnsiStringT$us$i0$%t2ro][539]
FDED283 [System.pas][System][@IntfClear$qqrr44System.%DelphiInterface$17System.IInterface%][36327]
6EBEC5 [uTCP.pas][uTCP][TProcElem.Proc$qqr55System.%DelphiInterface$28Uglobalinterface.IDBProvider%54System.%DelphiInterface$27Uglobalinterface.IEncr%][541]
42F5F0 [System.SysUtils.pas][System.SysUtils][Sysutils.TryEncodeTime$qqrususususr16System.TDateTime][18655]
42F62B [System.SysUtils.pas][System.SysUtils][Sysutils.EncodeTime$qqrusususus][18662]

The block is currently used for an object of class: TList
```

А когда в конце получаю файл с отчетом об утечках, то стек не расшифрован:

```
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 20

This block was allocated by thread 0x2398, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
FDE6C42 
FDE78FB 
FDE8076 
FDE79F0 
FED9E67 
FED9E73 
FED5D9F 
FDED283 
6EBEC5 [uTCP.pas][uTCP][TProcElem.Proc$qqr55System.%DelphiInterface$28Uglobalinterface.IDBProvider%54System.%DelphiInterface$27Uglobalinterface.IEncr%][541]
42F5F0 [System.SysUtils.pas][System.SysUtils][Sysutils.TryEncodeTime$qqrususususr16System.TDateTime][18655]
42F62B [System.SysUtils.pas][System.SysUtils][Sysutils.EncodeTime$qqrusususus][18662]

The block is currently used for an object of class: Unknown
```

Вопросы:

1. А почему полный стек в отчете по утечкам не выводится? И как сделать, что бы выводился?
2. В детализации стека странные данные "$qqrx24System.%DynamicArray$uc%rir27System.%AnsiStringT$us$i0$%t2ro" - что это такое? откуда может быть?